# No Real-time Update from New Nav

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, new-nav

I have set-up the New-Nav as

- main tab: new
- filter  : custom Tags (`C`)
- show    : all
- sort    : newest
- layout  : expanded layout

<sup>Screenshot below</sup>

But, I am not getting the real-time update for new questions.

I am running on chrome 43+ and have an extension Chrome Notifier enabled.

- **Earlier**, the page used to display the in-browser notification first, after some time (1~2 mins), the extension notification used to come.
- **Now**, Even after getting the notification from the extension, I'm not seeing the in-browser update at all. I did require to refresh manually.

Repro or solution, anyone?

FYR, screenshot of my set up.

[image: New-Nav setup]

---

UPDATE:

[Cross-Meta Linked post in MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256862/244062)

---

Update 2:

[30-June-2015] Fixed.

Comment: I'm seeing this happen without the filter as well.

Comment: Supposedly fixed. I guess not :(

Comment: Can confirm that the notifications are not present.

Comment: @Sklivvz It's not fixed. I'm **still** facing the same issue.

Comment: @Sklivvz still...stilll....

Comment: Yes, still broken.

Comment: Not working for me in "newest"

Comment: I can confirm fixed. Good work people!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally this is fixed, (sorry for late answer to update). Cheers!!

Sample screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Working for me in "Need Answers"

**Not working** in "New Questions" although the *asked {} hours ago* seems to be working.

[image: new]

[image: Need answers seems to work]

Comment: Not working for me in aforesaid configuration at the time of positing this comment.