# What to do with an (apparent) wrong status-complete tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

> *I wish a Meta MSO existed.....*

I asked [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297627/2173917) question, which is tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and (I believe) wrongly tagged as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) by an employee.

I'm still facing the issue, it is not resolved. Other than leaving a comment, shall I (and *can* I) remove the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) ?

---

EDIT:

(If it matters) One of the many [Cross-Meta MSE dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259384/244062) is still status "open".

---

EDIT 2:

[Another Cross-Meta Dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256862/244062), marked completed, but the follow-up points otherwise.

Comment: If I see an incorrect [tag:status-completed], I always raise a custom flag explaining why [the tag] is incorrect.

Comment: Meta Meta SO is just Meta SO again. As is Meta Meta Meta SO.

Comment: @durron597 yes, it's like `const const int a;`. I know. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just comment on the question and reply to the mod that added the tag if you're unsure if it's correct.  In this case, as they marked it completed, you can explain why you think its not completed and ask them why they marked it as completed.  They can then either correct the tag, or explain to you why the status is appropriate.

Comment: As you can see, I kept commenting regarding the same (which got upvotes, means others are experiencing , too) but no response.....

Comment: I also expressed my concern in the cross-meta post (see edit 2), too, where he has posted an answer.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Then you've done all you can do.  If they aren't responding you can't *make* them respond.

Comment: I know i don't need to make them respond, just wondering if we can do anything to get the attention, because naturally, [one does not simply](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r21CMDyPuGo) re-visits status-completed post. :-)