# Is Stack Overflow updating times on questions, comments, answers more slowly (and not spotting new comments, answers as quickly)?

Tags: discussion, new-nav, ssl

Are you seeing Stack Overflow show updates to the times on questions, answers and comments — and collecting/displaying new answers and comments and other updates to questions — much more slowly than it did a week or two ago?

I've noticed this for a week or more now, and it's been frustrating as I don't get notifications of other people's answers, so I spend time only to find out that other people have been working too.

I'm using the 'New Nav'; however, the [No Real-time Upate from New Nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297627/no-real-time-update-from-new-nav) bug was fixed in June 2015; this means it's either a regression or a new version of the bug.

Before asking here, I've looked on both Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange and not seen anyone comment on it, but it's been bugging me for days — I wondered if it was just my system. But after an update to Firefox 41, I'm moderately sure it's not just my system. I also checked with someone else, and having pitched my question with the word 'catastrophic' in it (I've made this version less dramatic), I got the response:

> @JonathanLeffler: Catastrophic is fleeing from Syria and encountering Hungary :) But I do find SO to be updating irregularly, yes. I presume it is some kind of caching issue.

I accept that 'catastrophe' is relative, and my use of it was gross hyperbole.

---

*Update: 2015-10-20.*

After the passage of some time, some cogitation, and some mild experimentation, I think I'm ready to cast some of the 'blame', if blame is the right term, on the Firefox [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/HTTPS-everywhere) extension from [EFF](https://www.eff.org/).

The limited proof-point is a Firefox browser (38.3.0 ESR) which did not have HTTPS Everywhere installed had been responding timely to updates, etc.  This morning, I added HTTPS Everywhere to the browser, and I think the updates have stopped happening on time.  I will need to do more experimentation, and should probably disable or even uninstall the extension to see whether the behaviour reverts, and probably try the same on the other machine where I first noticed the problem.

*[…Later the same day…]*

I temporarily disabled HTTPS Everywhere on my main machine, which runs Firefox 41.0.2 now, and the updates went back to working normally.  So, I'm moderately convinced that the problem I am/was seeing on SO is related to that plugin.  I'll leave this around in case it helps anyone else, but I don't know whether there's anything that can be done about it.  I plan to continue using the plugin; I think I'm going to continue using it even on SO.

Comment: strange no comments on this... i disable cache completely in firefox by default. In chrome where I don't have cache disabled have to constantly do hard refreshes, especially when using back button where lists are often older than my last visit

Comment: @charlietfl I think it has more to do with the server side caching.

Comment: Finally someone managed to slow down time. My weekends will now last longer.

Comment: @charlietfl: Would you — or, indeed, anybody else — be willing to explain how to disable the caching in Firefox?  In the Preferences page, Advanced section, Network tab, there's 'Cached web content' with a size; do you simply set that to 0?  How much impact does that have on general browsing?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That depends on your connection. No caching means you have to retrieve all pages every time, but if you have fast Internet it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I do it through *"Web Developer Toolbar"* add-on. With fast connection there is little impact

Comment: @JonathanLeffler On a fast connection it has little impact on you, but do the internet a favour and don't disable caching... it was made with a reason ;-) .

Comment: @DavidMulder caching was invented to [blame](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)