# Unable to get real time updates for new questions in the new tab system

Tags: support, new-nav

Since, the new tab system has been put in place, I've not been able to get the 'new question' notification when I select the 'newest' filter.

These are the tags I'm following (copied it from the search query text field):

```
[python] or [python-2.7] or [selenium] or [selenium-webdriver] or [django] or [beautifulsoup] or [python-requests] or [xpath] or [web-scraping] or [django-models] or [django-forms] or [django-templates] or [django-admin] or [django-views] or [django-rest-framework] or [django-queryset] or [django-urls] or [django-orm] or [django-haystack] or [django-south] or [django-cms] or [django-authentication] or [django-celery] or [django-class-based-views] or [django-allauth] or [django-registration] or [django-testing] or [django-staticfiles] or [django-settings]
```

URL to the custom tab - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python%20or%20python-2.7%20or%20selenium%20or%20selenium-webdriver%20or%20django%20or%20beautifulsoup%20or%20python-requests%20or%20xpath%20or%20web-scraping%20or%20django-models%20or%20django-forms%20or%20django-templates%20or%20django-admin%20or%20django-views%20or%20django-rest-framework%20or%20django-queryset%20or%20django-urls%20or%20django-orm%20or%20django-haystack%20or%20django-south%20or%20django-cms%20or%20django-authentication%20or%20django-celery%20or%20django-class-based-views%20or%20django-allauth%20or%20django-registration%20or%20django-testing%20or%20django-staticfiles%20or%20django-settings)

Even with the filter set to 'newest' I get no notification

[image]

I have to always refresh to get the newest questions. Check the [screenshot 1 (before refresh)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqfSm.jpg) and [screenshot 2 (after refresh)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuAr5.jpg).

Where am I going wrong? Or is this a bug?

**NOTE:**

1. I've not added the [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) tag to question yet, as I'm not really sure about it.
2. Plus, I've referred some questions on MSO/MSE but they've haven't helped me in resolving my issue. [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297627/2932244), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256862/313565)

Comment: New tab system? Why am I not seeing this?

Comment: @TJ - in your profile preferences there is a setting to test the new navigation / tab system, you have to manually check it to TRUE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `or` confuses it a great deal; however, if you *omit* the `or`, and simply change the mode to "any" (rather than "all"), it works; [here's a working link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python%20python-2.7%20selenium%20selenium-webdriver%20django%20beautifulsoup%20python-requests%20xpath%20web-scraping%20django-models%20django-forms%20django-templates%20django-admin%20django-views%20django-rest-framework%20django-queryset%20django-urls%20django-orm%20django-haystack%20django-south%20django-cms%20django-authentication%20django-celery%20django-class-based-views%20django-allauth%20django-registration%20django-testing%20django-staticfiles%20django-settings?mode=any) that subscribes to realtime for all the tags.

Comment: Thanks! That link did work. I used to use the older link (the one with the `or`'s) before the new tab system, to get latest questions.

Comment: @JRodDynamite yes, the "or" version works fine in the old UI; we're trying to figure out what happened there

Comment: Should I add the `bug` tag to this question?

Comment: I ran into that as soon as the UI switch happened. I guess I should've reported it instead of assuming "works as intended".